# How to change kernel security level from 0 to 1 after `sysctl kern.securelevel`

Tags: macos, security, kernel

When I run `sysctl kern.securelevel` on my Mac, it gives me a value of 0.

I'd like to increase the kernel security level on my computer. I want it to give me a 1.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
sysctl kern.securelevel=1
```

Comment: I'm concerned that the work-around is to delete the line in sysctl.conf. Can I lock the file?